# Why Kaidou cant die?

Tags: one-piece

In his appearances of manga , kaidou is shown to jump down from sorajima and still live. The mystery still remains that he doesnt die even after doing this? 
why is this so ? Mythical fruit users don't die, is it the case ?

[image]

Is he similarto charlotte linlin who also doesnt die even after suffering from many things ?

Comment: The manga has not revealed the full powers and secrets of Kaidou. We do not even know his devil fruit yet. Till we get these answers, people can only theorise why he can't die.

There are many theories why he can't die, one being that he is not a human but a real dragon itself and he has eaten the human-human fruit model demon.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that Kaido can not die, it's that he's so strong and so powerful that it's not enough to kill him.

That's why he has the title of `The Strongest Creature` in the world.

Also, there is a theory that Kaido is actually a creation of Dr. Vegapunk and his body is made of steel, giving him immense strength.

Comment: Imagine that boss fight: Luffy fights kaido for 10 episodes, finally goes all out using his than strongest gear/technique and only manages to scratch Kaido but that's enought for Franky to realizes the nature of their opponent and thus to disable Kaido in a snap using his timeskip-knowledge.

Comment: To be more precise: it is not even enough for him to get a single scratch, just a good headache (in fact probably largely due to the drinking of the previous day)